# href #div_name?id="" PHP

Tags: php, mysql, html, forms, get

Is it possible to attach the data to the url like this?

```
<?php
$query = mysql_query(......) or die(mysql_error());
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
    echo "<a href='#foo?id=" . $row['Id'] . "'>" . $row['Name'] . "</a>";
}
?>
<div id="foo">
    <form action="process.php" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $_GET['id'] ?>"/>
        <input type="text" name="message" value=""/>
        <input type="submit" name="sendMessage" value="Send Message"/>
    </form>
</div>
```

I want to pass the `$row['Id']` to the div so that it can be put in the value of the hidden input type. Thank you for your answers and suggestions!

Comment: Don't forget the quotes around the PHP code: value='<?php echo... ?>' />

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing your code like this.

```
<?php

$query = mysql_query(......) or die(mysql_error());
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
    echo "<a href='#foo?id=" . $row['Id'] . "'>" . $row['Name'] . "</a>";
    $id = $row['Id'] ;
}
?>
<div id="foo">
    <form action="process.php" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $id ; ?>"/>
        <input type="text" name="message" value=""/>
        <input type="submit" name="sendMessage" value="Send Message"/>
    </form>
</div>
```

Cheers!

Prasad.

Comment: I did not delete anything here.

Comment: Doesn't the #foo need to be after any ?var=bar in the URL?

Comment: @PrasadRajapaksha I'm so sorry. Maybe the someone who posted that deleted his own answer. It really looks like the code of yours. BTW, Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to take the row number that is clicked on and then make that the value for the hidden input, You probably want to use some javascript/jQuery. Its not even that difficult. Take a look at an example I made [here](http://jsfiddle.net/bgBXG/)

Comment: That will be really helpful! thanks for your effort. I'll implement that. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php echo "<div id=".$_GET['id'].">"?>....html....</div>
```

When you loop this, I don't know how you're applying it but if it's with a lot of other stuff, you might want to consider building an array and then outputting to a template format.